# Find the minimum of $a + b + c$

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c$ be non-negative real numbers such that

$$abc[(a − b)(b − c)(c − a)]^2 = 1$$

Find the minimum of $a + b + c$.

**Source:** https://cms.math.ca/crux/v43/n5/public_Chow_et_al_43_5.pdf

**My Attempt:**

$a \mapsto \frac{x+y}{2}$

$b \mapsto \frac{y+z}{2}$

$c \mapsto \frac{x+z}{2}$ $\;$ without any success

Comment: After your substitution you'll obtain that the variables can be negative.

Comment: I don't think this can be solved by hand. By computer, minima is around $3.179585909925689...$ for $(a,b,c)\sim (0.1468878830789771..., 0.8105401645853511..., 2.222157862261361...)$

Comment: @Atticus thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**: The minimum of $a+b+c$ is $\sqrt[9]{\frac{531441}{16}}$. Let us prove it.

First, let $p_0 = \sqrt[9]{\frac{531441}{16}}, q_0 = \sqrt[9]{1458}$ and $r_0 = \sqrt[9]{\frac{1}{157464}}$.
The cubic equation $x^3 - p_0x^2 + q_0x - r_0 = 0$ has three distinct positive real roots denoted by $x_1, x_2, x_3$.
Let $a = x_1, b = x_2, c= x_3$. Then $a + b + c = p_0 = \sqrt[9]{\frac{531441}{16}}$ and (noting that $2p_0^3-243r_0 = 0$
and $2p_0^2-9q_0 = 0$)
\begin{align}
abc(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 &= r_0(-4p_0^3r_0+p_0^2q_0^2+18p_0q_0r_0-4q_0^3-27r_0^2)\\
&= \frac{16}{531441}p_0^9\\
&= 1.
\end{align}

Thus, it suffices to prove that for $a, b, c > 0$, 
$$f(a,b,c) = 16(a+b+c)^9 - 531441abc(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \ge 0.$$
We use the pqr method. Let $p = a + b + c$, $q = ab+bc+ca$ and $r = abc$. 
Then 
\begin{align}
f(a,b,c) &= 2125764rq^3-531441p^2rq^2-9565938pr^2q\\
&\quad +2125764p^3r^2+16p^9+14348907r^3.
\end{align}
We split into two cases:

1) $2 p^3-243 r = 0$: By using $r = \frac{2p^3}{243}$, we have
$f(a,b,c) = 6p^3(7p^2+36q)(2p^2-9q)^2\ge 0 $.

2) $2 p^3-243 r \ne 0$: For each fixed $p, r > 0$, let
\begin{align}
g(q) &= 2125764rq^3-531441p^2rq^2-9565938pr^2q\\
&\quad +2125764p^3r^2+16p^9+14348907r^3.
\end{align}
$g(q)$ is a cubic polynomial whose discriminant is
\begin{align}
\mathrm{discr}(g) = -122009559759792 r^2(2 p^3-243 r)^2h(r, p)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
h(r,p) &= (64p^{12}-4131p^9r+260^2p^6r^2) \\
&\quad + r^2(8612603p^6-330024861p^3r+3486784401r^2)\\
&\ge (2\sqrt{64p^{12} \cdot 260^2p^6r^2} - 4131p^9r)\\
&\quad + r^2(2\sqrt{8612603p^6 \cdot 3486784401r^2} - 330024861p^3r)\\
&> 0.
\end{align}
Since $\mathrm{discr}(g) < 0$, 
the cubic equation $g(q) = 0$ has exactly one real root on $(-\infty, +\infty)$.
Also, $g(+\infty) = +\infty$ and $g(0) = 16p^9+2125764p^3r^2+14348907r^3 > 0$.
Thus, $g(q) > 0$ for any $q > 0$.

We are done.

Comment: Great solution, Thank you!

Comment: @TahaDirek You are welcome. It is an interesting problem.  $abc(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2=1$ makes $abc\ne 0$ and $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\ne 0$. Actually, I hope to see simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

*Remarks*: @youthdoo said there is a AM-GM solution. I found it.

**Problem**: Let $a, b, c\ge 0$ with $abc[(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)]^2 = 1$. Prove that
$$a + b + c \ge \sqrt[9]{\frac{531441}{16}}.$$

**Sketch of a proof**:

WLOG, assume that $a > b > c$.

Let $0 < x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ be the three real roots of $2x^3 - 54x^2 + 243x - 243 = 0$.
Let
$$x_4 = \frac{x_1x_2}{x_2 - x_1}, \quad x_5 = \frac{9 - x_2}{2} + \frac{x_1x_2}{x_2 - x_1}, \quad
x_6 = \frac{9 - x_1}{2} - \frac{x_1x_2}{x_2 - x_1}.$$
It is easy to prove that $x_4, x_5, x_6 > 0$.

By AM-GM, we have
\begin{align*}
 &x_1x_2x_3x_4^2x_5^2x_6^2\cdot abc[(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)]^2\\
 ={}&x_1a \cdot x_2b \cdot x_3c \cdot x_4(a - b) \cdot x_4(a - b) \cdot x_5(b - c) \cdot x_5(b - c) \cdot x_6(a - c) \cdot x_6 (a - c) \\
 \le{}& \left(\frac{x_1a + x_2b + x_3c + x_4(a-b) \times 2 + x_5(b - c) \times 2 + x_6(a-c)\times 2}{9}\right)^9\\
 ={}& \left(\frac{(x_1+2x_4+2x_6)a + (x_2-2x_4+2x_5)b + (x_3-2x_5-2x_6)c}{9}\right)^9\\
 ={}& (a + b + c)^9
\end{align*}
where we have used $x_1 + 2x_4 + 2x_6 = 9$, $x_2 - 2x_4 + 2x_5 = 9$, and
$x_3 - 2x_5 - 2x_6 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - 18 = 9$ (by Vieta's theorem).

It suffices to prove that
$$x_1x_2x_3x_4^2x_5^2x_6^2 = \frac{531441}{16}.$$
Using $x_1x_2x_3 = \frac{243}{2}$ (by Vieta's theorem), it suffices to prove that
$$(x_4x_5x_6)^2 = \frac{2187}{8}$$
which is true. The proof is omitted here.

We are done.

Comment: Great proof, so how did you find the coefficients?

Comment: @youthdoo We get six equations for example $x_1 + 2x_4 + 2x_6 = 9$ ...

Comment: For me, I got some of them not linear, is it like that?

Comment: @youthdoo The equations are: $x_1 + 2x_4 + 2x_6 = 9$, $x_2 - 2x_4 + 2x_5 = 9$, and
$x_3 - 2x_5 - 2x_6 = 9$; $x_1a = x_2 b = x_3 c = x_4(a-b)  = x_5(b - c) = x_6(a - c)$. Eliminating $x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6$, we get an equation in $x_1$ which is a solution of a cubic.